# SOAP Fault vs HTTP 400

Tags: http, soap, put

Is there some specification that says whether a Web-Server shall return HTTP 400 (Bad Request) or simply a SOAP Fault message in case I send a correct HTTP Post request to the server, however containing a bad SOAP Request. "A bad SOAP Request" in that case means a valid XML document, which does not start with the usual triple of SOAP Elements:

```
<soapenv:Envelope>....
<soapenv:Header>...
<soapenv:Body>...
```

but instead directly with a XML element like this:

```
<namespace:elem .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything official at the moment, Based on experience would get a 400 HTTP if your XML is malformed and a SOAP fault message if there is a value of some sort not correct in the SOAP message.

One thing to remember HTTP is one protocol used by SOAP services. You could run SOAP services via STMP(email) or other protocols if you wanted. HTTP is merely the transport. Thus including these specific of HTTP in a standards document is not needed. HTTP 400in SOAP terms means really bad message cant deliver.

For example a malformed xml like below should give HTTP 400:

```
 <nonsense>  <!-- opening tag with no closing tag-->
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ecol="http://www.blahblahablha">
 <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
      <ecol:GetDatabaseConnectionInfo/>
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

In the example below my message has a GUID which has a value of `?` which is a fault however since the XML is correctly formed the message is returned in a SOAP fault message.

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ec="http://www.blahablha.au/foo" xmlns:irix="http://www.blahblah/IRIX_Headers_V1" xmlns:irix1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IRIXContract.MsgHeaderBase">
    <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
      <ec:GetAccountActiveArrangement>
       <ec:GetAccountActiveArrangementReq>
         <irix:MsgReqHdr>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <irix:MsgGUID>?</irix:MsgGUID>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <irix:MsgDateTime>?</irix:MsgDateTime>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <irix:SecCredInfo>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <irix:IRIXUserID>?</irix:IRIXUserID>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <irix:IRIXPassword>?</irix:IRIXPassword>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <irix:AuthToken>?</irix:AuthToken>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <irix:ConsumerSystemID>?</irix:ConsumerSystemID>
           </irix:SecCredInfo>
        </irix:MsgReqHdr>
        <ec:accountNumber>70001</ecol:accountNumber>

  </ec:GetAccountActiveArrangement>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Sending this results in the following error:

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
   <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en-AU">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://www.blah blah/ECollNXDB_V1:GetAccountActiveArrangementReq. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type IRIXNXSoapServices.Message.Operations.Account.Get.GetAccountActiveArrangementReqV1. The value '?' cannot be parsed as the type 'Guid'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
           <InnerException>
              <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
              <InnerException>
                 <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
                 <InnerException>
                    <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
                    <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
                    <Message>Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).</Message>
```

This is standard behaviour.